# What does MPC stand for in MPC SONIA futures?

Tags: cme-group

CME Group launched [MPC SONIA](https://youtu.be/Z4DgpZ3b59Q?t=135) futures contracts in October 2018.

SONIA stands for Sterling Overnight Index Average Rate, yet I couldn't find what the MPC is for.

Comment: "[CME Group](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/sonia-futures.html) will launch two new SONIA futures: a quarterly International Monetary Market (IMM) dated contract observing the recommended specifications of the Working Group on Sterling Risk Free Reference Rates; and a Bank of England Monetary Policy Committee (MPC) meeting dated contract. The MPC SONIA futures contract is designed to meet the needs of market participants who require greater precision in managing exposure between the dates of the MPC meetings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found it in the [contract specifications](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/mpc-sonia-futures_contract_specifications.html):

> For a given contract, interval from (and including) scheduled Monetary Policy Committee (MPC) announcement date in Contract Month, to (and not including) scheduled MPC announcement date in Delivery Month.